# How to allow elements AT THE SAME allow custom attribute in HTMLPurifier?

Tags: htmlpurifier

I am going to add a custom attribute 'custom-type' with "a" element, at the same time only allow "h1" and "a" element.

I try following codes:

```
    $config= HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
    $config->set('Attr.EnableID',true);
    $def = $config->getHTMLDefinition(true);
    $def->addAttribute('a', 'custom-type', 'Text');
    $config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'h1,a[href|id|custom-type]');
    $html_purifier = new \HTMLPurifier($config);        
    $clean_html = $html_purifier->purify($str);
```

It generates errors like below:

"Cannot set directive after finalization invoked on line 69 in file "

I am wondering what is wrong with above codes. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this question. It works after changing order of above codes like this:

```
$config= HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('Attr.EnableID',true);
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'h1,a[href|id|custom-type]');
$def = $config->getHTMLDefinition(true);
$def->addAttribute('a', 'custom-type', 'Text');
$html_purifier = new \HTMLPurifier($config);        
$clean_html = $html_purifier->purify($str);
```

Set rules first, then set getHTMLDefinition(true) to true to retrieve a copy of previously set rules, finally add custom attribute.